# How to customise Identity Models to rename columns and resize datatypes in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, identityserver4

I've been playing around with [this quickstart example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage) & have been trying to see how far I can customise the database (I have an existing database I've been half-trying to replicate).

I'm trying my hand at renaming fields and redefining the datatypes but have run into the following error:

> InvalidOperationException:
>   'Role.NormalisedName' and 'Role.NormalizedName' are both mapped to column 'NormalisedName' in 'Roles' but are configured to use different data types ('nvarchar(max)' and 'nvarchar(256)').

The entity that customises `IdentityRole` currently looks like this:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public int RoleId
    {
        get => base.Id;
        set => base.Id = value;
    }
    public string NormalisedName
    {
        get => base.NormalizedName;
        set => base.NormalizedName = value;
    }

    public ICollection<RoleClaim> ClaimsCollection { get; set; }
}
```

And the override in the `ApplicationDbContext` looks like this:

```
// "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole"
ModelBuilder.Entity<Role>(E =>
{
    E.Property(P => P.Id)
        .HasColumnName("RoleId")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

    E.Property(P => P.ConcurrencyStamp)
        .HasMaxLength(512)
        .IsConcurrencyToken();

    E.Property(P => P.Name)
    .HasMaxLength(128);

    E.Property(P => P.NormalizedName)
        .HasMaxLength(128)
        .HasColumnName("NormalisedName");

    E.HasKey(P => P.Id);

    E.HasIndex(P => P.NormalizedName)
        .IsUnique()
        .HasName("IX_Roles_NormalisedName");

    E.ToTable("Roles");
});
```

The "Roles" table in the database has a width of `nvarchar(512)` set on both the `Name` and `NormalisedName` columns; this is due to the index on `NormalisedName`, which will warn on the length of a key in a nonclustered index exceeding 1700 bytes. The warning generated will look like this:

> Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'IX_Roles_NormalisedName' has maximum length of 2048 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

Does anyone have any idea how (or even if) I can impose this limit on this field? Specifying the `HasMaxLength()` extension method alone doesn't appear to work as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I was seeing the error was due to my attempt at redefining the column, as opposed to replacing the field and providing a fresh definition for how I wanted the data to be stored in SqlServer.

Because I was overlaying my edits on the existing stuff in `IdentityDbContext`, `ModelBuilder` could see both fields and was trying to wedge everything together a little haphazardly.

A better example of renaming and removing columns from an Identity object would be the `IdentityUser`, so I'll use that as an example as it has more things I wanted to change in it.

The default layout of the object looks as follows:

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);
    public virtual DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

Say we're working database-first and I want to make various changes, like...

- make the key `Id` an integer (and the column has the 'identity' attribute in SqlServer)
- rename the table
- remove the `LockoutEnd` field
- remove the `PhoneNumberConfirmed` field
- remove the `PhoneNumber` field
- remove the `LockoutEnabled` field
- remove the `AccessFailedCount` field
- and rename the `Id`, `NormalizedEmail` and `NormalizedUserName` fields

Easy enough in theory, and in practice providing you know exactly where to look... I actually found the answer to this by accident, trying to resolve another problem. So, from the top.

Starting from a new "User" object, I needed to first ensure the key type was set.

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
}
```

In my case, because I wanted to rename the field as well as change the type, it made more sense to entirely redefine it; `Id` became `AccountId` to make the identifier consistent throughout all of my tables.

```
public int AccountId { get; set; }
```

This is then backed-up in the DbContext (in my case `CustomerDbContext`), the key type change needs to be confirmed here, this was the standard change to the `IdentityDbContext` inheritance to specify the types it should be using.

```
public partial class CustomerDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
}
```

Within this, and after `base.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder);`, I had to define the key to use for this object.

We may as well change the table name while we're here too.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder ModelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder);

    ModelBuilder.Entity<User>(Entity =>
    {
        Entity.HasKey(E => E.AccountId);

        Entity.ToTable("Users");
    });
}
```

The `Id` field will still raise its' ugly head, but that will be sorted when we remove the fields we don't want from `IdentityUser`.

To rename the `NormalizedEmail` and `NormalizedUserName` fields, you can just specify the column name for them when building the `User` entity, for example:
ql("(getdate())");

```
Entity.Property(E => E.NormalizedEmail)
    .HasColumnName("NormalisedEmail")
    .IsRequired();

Entity.Property(E => E.NormalizedUserName)
    .HasColumnName("NormalisedUserName");
```

Nice and easy, but you can't change the column definition as far as I can tell, so adding `.HasMaxLength(512)` to either column, for instance, will make it bug out (the default column width is 450). This is actually the cause of the first error message in my question.

> InvalidOperationException: 'Role.NormalisedName' and
>   'Role.NormalizedName' are both mapped to column 'NormalisedName' in
>   'Roles' but are configured to use different data types
>   ('nvarchar(max)' and 'nvarchar(256)').

I found it easier to fully redefine the fields; adding

```
// I _think_ the original fields are used internally, so I
// couldn't dispense with them entirely.
public string NormalisedEmail
{
    get => NormalizedEmail;
    set => NormalizedEmail = value.ToLowerInvariant();
}
public string NormalisedUserName
{
    get => NormalizedUserName;
    set => NormalizedUserName = value.ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

to my `User` class, and

```
Entity.Property(E => E.NormalisedEmail)
    .IsRequired()
    .HasMaxLength(512);

Entity.Property(E => E.NormalisedUserName)
    .HasMaxLength(512);
```

to my `Entity<User>` definition in `CustomerDbContext`.

Finally, to remove all of the unused fields, and the lingering `Id`, `NormalizedEmail` and `NormalizedUserName` fields that are now redefined; simply specify that they should be ignored by the `ModelBuilder`, using:

```
Entity.Ignore(E => E.Id)
    .Ignore(E => E.AccessFailedCount)
    .Ignore(E => E.LockoutEnabled)
    .Ignore(E => E.LockoutEnd)
    .Ignore(E => E.NormalizedEmail)
    .Ignore(E => E.NormalizedUserName)
    .Ignore(E => E.PhoneNumber)
    .Ignore(E => E.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
```

This was just about enough to allow me to design my project database-first and then bend Identity/IdentityServer around the tables.